TestNG testng-failed.xml 'invocation-numbers' values are not calculated correctly with retry and dataproviders?
In one of our Java project we use TestNG's dataprovider and retry mechanism quite a lot. We came accross a weird behaviour and can't decide whether it is a bug, or expected behaviour of TestNG.
In short: When running a test with dataprovider and retries, if a test for a certain given data-provider value eventually passes after a retry, it still gets generated in the testng-failed.xml if that method has a failed invocation (after all retries) with a different value.
Let me share the code I have.
RetryAnalyzer.java
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    int counter = 0;
    int retryLimit = 1;

    /*
     * Retry method
     */
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            if (counter < retryLimit) {
                System.out.println(" ... FAILURE! Retrying ... (#" + (counter + 1) + " out of " + retryLimit + ")");
                counter++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

RetryTest.java
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Random;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RetryTest {
    
    @Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class, dataProvider = "dp")
    public void testDataProvider(int number) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(3) + 1;  // Generates a number between 1 and 3
        System.out.println("Number from data-provider: " + number);
        System.out.println("Generated number: " + randomNumber);
        assertEquals(randomNumber, number, "The two values are different!");
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] createTestData() {
        return new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };
    }
}

We should examine a scenario when one of the test values completely fails (even after a retry), but the other one (i.e.: invocation with another data-provider value) passes after a failure.
Number from data-provider: 1
Generated number: 2
 ... FAILURE! Retrying ... (#1 out of 1)
Number from data-provider: 1
Generated number: 1
Number from data-provider: 2
Generated number: 1
 ... FAILURE! Retrying ... (#1 out of 1)
Number from data-provider: 2
Generated number: 1
Number from data-provider: 3
Generated number: 1
 ... FAILURE! Retrying ... (#1 out of 1)
Number from data-provider: 3
Generated number: 3
PASSED: restAPITest.boards.BoardsTest.testDataProvider(3)
PASSED: restAPITest.boards.BoardsTest.testDataProvider(1)
FAILED: restAPITest.boards.BoardsTest.testDataProvider(2)

As it can be seen, for data-provider value '2', both test-runs failed, since overall it FAILED. But for the values '1' and '3' the test eventually succeded after a failure.
But when I open the testng-failed.xml file which is generated after this test run, I can see the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Failed suite [Default suite]" guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Default test(failed)">
    <classes>
      <class name="RetryTest">
        <methods>
          <include name="testDataProvider" invocation-numbers="0 1 2"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- RetryTest -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test(failed) -->
</suite> <!-- Failed suite [Default suite] -->

Notice the invocation-numbers part which includes all the indexes (i.e.: the 0th, 1st, and 2nd value of the data-provider) to be executed for a rerun.
I would expect that invocation-numbers would contain only those indexes that failed completely - meaning after all retries. (In this case only the index value '1' should be there, since that represents the value '2' of the data-provider.)
Can somebody clarify me this behaviour?

I believe you had filed this as a defect as well https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/3180. I have fixed this and the changes will be part of the next release of TestNG 7.11.0

Thank you @KrishnanMahadevan!
